# How to flatten this json as a tsv?

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq, flatten

I'd like to flatten this JSON to a tsv file.

https://www.vi4io.org/assets/io500/2019-06/data.json

The problem is that each entry (the first level of {}) has many fields/subfields. I don't want to specify so many field names. And there is no guarantee that the fields/subfields are the same across all the entries. Therefore, I'd like the result column contains a union of all the fileds/subfields. The columns names should be ordered as close as possible as the original json file. (E.g., those subfields in the same field should be listed together in the tsv).

What is the best way to convert this json file to tsv? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of a shady link include an excerpt from your input. And an output example would also be very helpful

Comment: user1424739 - I have not down-voted your question, but if you'd like to avoid further downvotes, firstly do what @OguzIsmail suggested (provide a very brief example that illustrates the points that are key to you), and secondly show at least one attempt you've made using a tool that would be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a jq solution which will work for any array of JSON objects, without restriction, but please see "Caveats" below.

## json2tsv.jq

```
# Given an array of JSON objects, 
# produce "TSV" rows, with a header row.
# Handle terminal arrays specially if they are flat.


# emit a stream
def json2headers:
  def isscalar: type | . != "array" and . != "object";
  def isflat: all(.[]; isscalar);
  paths as $p
  | getpath($p)
  | if type == "array" and isflat then $p
     elif isscalar and (($p[-1]|type) == "string") then $p
     else empty end ;

def json2array($header):
   [$header[] as $p | (try getpath($p) catch null)] ;

def json2tsv:
  ( [.[] | json2headers] | unique) as $h
  | ([$h[]|join("_") ],
     (.[]
      | json2array($h)
      | map( if type == "array" then map(tostring)|join("|") else tostring end)))
  | @tsv ;
```

### Usage

```
jq -r -L. 'include "json2tsv"; json2tsv' input.json
```

### Output

The input sample is very large, so here I'll just show the header, together with a separate example.

#### Header

```
find_easy   information_URL information_client_kernel_version   information_client_nodes    information_client_operating_system information_client_operating_system_version information_client_procs_per_node   information_comment information_data    information_ds_network  information_ds_nodes    information_ds_operating_system_version information_ds_software_version information_ds_storage_devices  information_ds_storage_interface    information_ds_storage_type information_ds_volatile_memory_capacity information_embargo_end_date    information_filesystem_name information_filesystem_type information_filesystem_version  information_id  information_institution information_list    information_md_network  information_md_nodes    information_md_operating_system_version information_md_software_version information_md_storage_devices  information_md_storage_interface    information_md_storage_type information_md_volatile_memory_capacity information_note    information_storage_install_date    information_storage_refresh_date    information_storage_vendor  information_submission_date information_submitter   information_system  information_vendorURL   information_whatever    io500_md    io500_score ior_easy_read   ior_easy_write  ior_hard_read   ior_hard_write  mdtest_easy_delete  mdtest_easy_stat    mdtest_easy_write   mdtest_hard_delete  mdtest_hard_read    mdtest_hard_stat    mdtest_hard_write
```

## Short examples

#### input.json

```
[ {a: [1,2], b: {c:3, d: [{e:4},{e:5, f:6}]}},
  {b: {d: [{e:4},{f:6, e:5}], c:3}, a:[101,102] } ]
```

Output

```
a   b_c b_d_0_e b_d_1_e b_d_1_f
1|2 3   4   5   6
101|102 3   4   5   6
```

#### input.json (Dmitry's variation)

```
[ {a:[1,2],b:{c:3,d:[{e:4},{e:5,f:6}]}},
  {b:{d:[{e:4},{f:6}],c:3},a:[101,102]} ]
```

Output

```
a   b_c b_d_0_e b_d_1_e b_d_1_f
1|2 3   4   5   6
101|102 3   4   null    6
```

#### Objects with different structures

```
[ {a: [1,2], b: {c: 3}},
  {a: [4,5], b: {c: {d: 6 } } }
```

Output

```
a   b_c b_c_d
1|2 3   null
4|5 {"d":6} 6
```

### Caveats

- For each object in the top-level array, the paths to all scalars and scalar-valued arrays is computed; if any such path is invalid in another top-level object, the corresponding value in the output will be `null`, as shown in the last example.
- Flat arrays are converted to pipe-separated values, so that if the input includes an array such as ["1|2", ["3|4"], it will be indistinguishable from the string value, "1|2|3|4", etc. If this is a problem, the character used as a separator value for array items can of course be changed.
- Similar collisions can occur with the header names.
- jq's `@tsv` produces an empty string for both `""` and `null`, so if it's important to distinguish between the two, you might wish to consider using an appropriate `map` before invoking `@tsv`.

Comment: though **jq** is not my business and I have upvoted your solution, knowing how diligent you are, could you please, update it, so that it also works correctly with _irregular jsons_ like: `[{a:[1,2],b:{c:3,d:[{e:4},{e:5,f:6}]}},{b:{d:[{e:4},{f:6}],c:3},a:[101,102]}]` - to make it comprehensive? - would be a good learning experience

Comment: @Dmitry - Good catch!  Updated. Thanks. Btw, is your `standard.json` already available somewhere? If not, could you please make it available?

Comment: let me think of the best way to host it, once done, I'll provide a link. Also, I see improved performance numbers for both jq and jtc on my new mac, so, I'll post its spec for the reference as well. will update you once done.

Comment: @Dmitry - Revised again to remove all restrictions on the input objects, but at the cost of possibly including entire objects in the TSV output (as shown in the new (last) example).

Comment: I have published `standard.json` and updated the performance figures (and published the comp. spec)

Answer (score 2):

If jq is not mandatory, you could use Miller https://github.com/johnkerl/miller

The command is

```
curl "https://www.vi4io.org/assets/io500/2019-06/data.json" | mlr --j2t unsparsify >output.tsv
```

If you want rename the output field names from something like `information:data` to `information_data` you can use `rename` verb in this way:

```
curl "https://www.vi4io.org/assets/io500/2019-06/data.json" | mlr --j2t unsparsify then rename -r '(.+):(.+),\1_\2' >output.tsv
```

Comment: How to change `information:data` to `information_data` in the header?

Comment: @user1424739 I have insert a related final note in my reply